# ArrayList not able to add elements due to the function call

Tags: java, arraylist

While running the below snippet the loop executes properly, but the elements are not added for some reason.

```
for(i=5;i<=500;i++) {
    x.add(i);
    check(x,i);
}

public static void check(ArrayList<Integer> x,Integer i){
    for(int j=0;j<x.size();j++){                                
        for(int k=0;k<x.size();k++){
            if(x.get(j)!=i&& x.get(k)!=i){
                if(x.contains(x.get(k)+x.get(j)))
                    x.remove(Integer.valueOf(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to remove duplicate values?

Comment: no no......it is supposed to remove the element for which there exists a pair whose sum is equal to that element.

Comment: Can you please include the rest of the code as it is hard to judge what is wrong with just this

Comment: can you guide me how to do that

Comment: Well, as you're iterating over a list on which you're removing items, you shouldn't expect anything else than an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. You're actually lucky it does nothing.

Comment: It appears that you are removing any number that you add.

Comment: At some point j + k = i in your code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: It is worked for me. After I checked it, output contains `5,6,..499` removing some middle values. you just need to iterate through the list `x` and see.

Comment: And even for the desired output, your algorithm is awful. As your list is sorted, you should only iterate until `x.get(j)>=i/2` and check if the rest of x contains `i - x.get(j)`. And you should check BEFORE adding, rather than adding and removing.

Comment: You should be adding if valid, not adding, and removing if invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the int i from the list instead of the computed value.  You do your contains method, you should remove that part.  Every time this is run it will remove whatever you plug in for i in the parameters.  So every time you add something you then just the method and delete what you just added.

Comment: no problem, hit me up with a check mark to let people know it is done and answered:)  Otherwise people will continue to post.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment was rather interesting, but the way you tried to do was really too expensive (and very wrong, because you modified the list during iteration)

So here's a bit of improvement :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    IntStream.range(5, 500)  
        .filter(i -> !check(list,i))    // check first
        .forEach( i -> list.add(i));    // add after
    System.out.println(list);
}
// we assume (rightly so) that list is ordered
private static boolean check(List<Integer> list, int value) {
    boolean found = false;
    for(int j=0; j < list.size(); j++){
        Integer leftSide = list.get(j);
        if(leftSide > value/2){   
            break;                  // as the check is symmetrical, stop after value/2 has been overtaken
        }
        Integer complementaryValue = value - leftSide;
        for(int k=j+1; k < list.size(); k++){  // iterate over the rest of the list (because right is necessarily > left)
            Integer rightSide = list.get(k);
            if(rightSide > complementaryValue){  
                break;              // no need to continue further
            }
            if(complementaryValue.equals(rightSide)){
                found = true;
                System.out.println(value+" = "+leftSide+" + "+rightSide);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found){
            break;  // or return true
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

You can try it.

This is still far from optimal, work can still be done on the inner loop. A dichotomic search for the complementary value would be way better.

The final list is

> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489]